# Lazy sequence returned but not sure why

Tags: clojure

I don't seem to remember that `str` returns a lazy sequence, yet the following:

```
(println (str "(" (map identity [1 2 3]) ")"))
```

produces the output:

```
(clojure.lang.LazySeq@7861)
```

and the following does not help

```
(println (doall (str "(" (map identity [1 2 3]) ")")))
```

This is stumping me so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT - to address difference from duplicate**

My intent is not for printing but was using in problem determination where I found that the lazy-seq return was the source of issue. I need the string to be realized prior to being consumed down-stream.

Comment: It's not. I'm not concerned about the println per-se but the fact that ```str``` returns a lazy-sequence

Comment: `str` returns a string, not a lazy sequence. `(str (map identity [1 2 3]))` evaluates to `"clojure.lang.LazySeq@7861"`. The possible duplicate solution seems to apply.

Comment: Thumbnail - Ahh, got-it!